# settings env variables on travis and ruby (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, travis-ci

I am using travis for one of my web apps, but I have some secret keys, so I need to store those as travis environ variables by following [here](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Set-environment-variables).

But when I tried the following command:

```
travis encrypt -r travis_username/app_name EMAIL_HOST=localhost.com
```

I got weird errors:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find travis (>= 0) amongst [addressable-2.3.5, backports-3.3.3, bundler-1.3.5, bundler-unload-1.0.1, coderay-1.0.9, ethon-0.6.0, faraday-0.8.8, faraday_middleware-0.9.0, ffi-1.9.0, gh-0.11.3, highline-1.6.19, launchy-2.3.0, method_source-0.8.2, mime-types-1.24, multi_json-1.7.9, multipart-post-1.2.0, net-http-persistent-2.9, net-http-pipeline-1.0.1, netrc-0.7.7, pry-0.9.12.2, pusher-client-0.3.1, rake-10.1.0, ruby-hmac-0.4.0, rubygems-bundler-1.2.2, rubygems-update-2.0.7, rvm-1.11.3.8, slop-3.4.6, typhoeus-0.6.4, websocket-1.0.7, websocket-native-1.0.0] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/travis:18
```

Can anyone please move me in the right direction and make the above installation work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `travis` gem:

`gem install travis`

or add it to the gemfile of the project you're currently using:

`gem "travis", "~> 1.5.2"`